Shouldn't this question be on another site on SE?
A recent question was asked when the user said that they were creating a model to 3D print. But the body of the question was mostly about "Crafting Perspex".
Am I mistaken but wouldn't the question be better suited for Arts & Crafts SE since it deals with cutting/shaping the acrylic?

That is why we have a voting system, if you think it is more appropriate at a different site, you can report this. If the initial report is filed, others may vote as well.
Looking at the content of arts and crafts, I'm unsure if it is a fit. It should be a fit though. Alternatively, acrylic is also used in interior decorating (e.g. to make a window indoors), so a DIY SE would be a fit as well. Personally, since the question contains a 3D print part, a move did not make much sense at the time.
Thanks to Davo to link to our What topics can I ask about here?, we do accept non 3D printing, but related questions.

Non-3D Printing related

CNC
Laser etching
Routers
Vacuum Forming
Parts assembly


Crafting perspex could fall under laser etching.

I do understand about the voting system (which I have used in this case). But I was surprised that an answer was posted, while it answers the question doesn't relate to 3D printing.

https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic includes the topics "laser etching" and "vacuum forming".
